# Setting custom font to Textview

Tags: android, custom-font, android-typeface

I am using custom fonts in my application
So I have used following code

```
public class BrandonBlackTextView extends TextView {

public BrandonBlackTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public BrandonBlackTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public BrandonBlackTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/brandon_blk.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);

}
```

wherever I wants to use I use this `textview`. It works.
But problem is sometimes I don't know why but text inside `textview` becomes **bold**. I don't know why this happening. And this is very inconsistent, it doesn't happen every time.

[image: in the pic, you see in one row text is bold.]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your init:

```
int flags = getPaintFlags() | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG |  Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG;
setPaintFlags(flags);
```

Also you should cache the typeface somewhere instead of loading it again for every `TextView`.

Comment: how to cache typeface?

Comment: @ShreenivasChikati Load it once and keep a reference to it.

Comment: ok, but int flags = getPaintFlags() | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG |  Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG;
setPaintFlags(flags); didn't help me

Comment: @ShreenivasChikati can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the issue?